# Would entropy increase if I smashed a glass inside the event horizon?

Tags: entropy, event-horizon

I read that eventually matters that fall into the event horizon will be shredded into fundamental particles and soon ended up in the singularity but if I were to shatter a piece of glass panel into smithereens while inside the event horizon then wouldn't the entropy increase? Or it increases ever so briefly then start to decrease?

Comment: Indeed, as per [Bekenstein Hawking entropy](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy)  $$S_{BH}={c^3 A\over 4 G \hbar}$$, black hole increases it's entropy as it grows it's surface area by absorbing matter.

Comment: Smashing a glass inside the event horizon shouldn't make the event horizon bigger.

Comment: What I mean is that absorbed matter finally get's decomposed into particles, hence this smashing of matter is going by itself in black hole, leaving only "informational traces" on the BH surface (increased surface area & entropy). However, I do not had in mind smashing glass inside even horizon at all. It's already (or will be smashed soon by BH itself), so it should make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The interior of the event horizon is not in the causal past of any event outside the horizon. You can foliate spacetime into spacelike surfaces that represent space at a given time. Such foliations could include the glass smashing event and events outside the horizon in one time-slice.

Calculating the entropy over that foliation would indeed show an increase in entropy compared to previous ones. Such an increase would not cause any measurable effect outside the horizon. So it is a bookkeeping kind of activity.